# Laravel - Listeners, Observers, Events, Jobs - What to use for adding user to a distro?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3. In Laravel sometimes I find myself wondering what is the best tool for a given job.

For instance, visitors can sign up for courses on my site. When they sign up, I have this in the course registration controller:

```
$registrant = CourseRegistrants::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['course_id' => $request->course_id, 'courseinstance_id' => $request->courseinstance_id]));
        $registrations = CourseRegistrants::where('email', $request->email)->pluck('id')->toArray();

$array_json=json_encode($registrations);

// set cookie by getting all webinars that the visitor registered for

return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for registering for the course!')->cookie('reg_id', $array_json, 1000);
```

So the question is, how would you implement the adding of the person to my Mailchimp distro? Would you `fire an event`? Would it be completed as a `job`? Or would you use a `Listener`? Or maybe an `Observer` on the registrants table?

Just trying to get a feel what you are all doing in this sort of use case.

thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts about this would be the Job Queue, because this asynchronous process (sucessfully saving data in your own DB and do something with the new data) seems to profit from the job states (success, failed) of the Job Queue itself - but this is just my quick opinion :-).

Comment: I am thinking along those lines too. Right now I have the registration controller firing a newregistration event and that being listened to by listener and then I suppose from listener that is where I would dispatch a queued job?